# Replicação de banco de dados em sistema WPF + EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, wpf

Eu tenho um sistema de venda em WPF / EF que esta em uso em diferentes cidades, mas a base de dados está na sede. Estou com problemas quando o link da cidade é muito lento, resultando consequentemente na lentidão da venda.

Eu consigo fazer uma replicação dessa minha base de dados para o server local e depois sincronizar com o meu servidor central?

Answer (score 1):

Acho que pro seu caso uma cache de segundo nível deve resolver. O Entity Framework tem um pacote que implementa isso. [Você pode baixá-lo aqui](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Cache).

[Segundo o blog do desenvolvedor, a configuração é bastante simples](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/03/20/second-level-cache-for-ef-6-1/). Coloque na sua classe de configuração o seguinte:

```
public class Configuration : DbConfiguration
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        var transactionHandler = new CacheTransactionHandler(Program.Cache);

        AddInterceptor(transactionHandler);

        Loaded +=
          (sender, args) => args.ReplaceService<DbProviderServices>(
            (s, _) => new CachingProviderServices(s, transactionHandler));
    }
}
```

Apenas isso já torna seu sistema mais fluido, sem necessidade de replicação de base. Entretanto, se a base crescer mais e a demanda também, não há mágica: é preciso investir na infraestrutura.